# When is static limit ($\omega=0$ and then $q=0$) of correlation function physical and used?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, greens-functions, correlation-functions

For a general correlation/response function $F(q,\omega)$, it can be both frequency and momentum dependent. And there are the so-called transport limit $$q\rightarrow0 \text{ and then }\omega\rightarrow0$$ and static limit $$\omega\rightarrow0 \:\mathrm{ and \;then }\:q\rightarrow0.$$ (Taking the dc conductivity as an example, it is well known that the transport limit of current-current correlator is the relevant thing.)

I want to ask about the static limit. In what circumstances does it become physical and for what response function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The static limit can become relevant in the type of zero-sound diagram (a bubble with two vertices), e.g., in the Fermi-liquid theory. It is evaluated as $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}d\omega\int_{-\Lambda}^{\Lambda}dk\frac{1}{(i\omega-k)(i\omega-k-Q+i\Omega)}=\int_{-\Lambda}^{\Lambda}dk\,i\frac{\theta(k)-\theta(k+Q)}{\Omega+iQ}$$
where $Q,\Omega$ are the external momentum and frequency transfer at the vertex.

If we take the transport limit, $Q\rightarrow0$ immediately gets us zero. However, if we take the static limit, $\Omega\rightarrow0$ and then $Q\rightarrow0$, we get a finite result.